# Dealing with jumps/discontinuities in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I was wondering if anyone had any tips or tricks in terms of dealing with jumps/discontinuities in Modelica. I'm using OpenModelica, and a simplified example code for my problem is shown below.

```
model PowerGenerator
  Modelica.SIunits.Power P(start=0);
  output Modelica.SIunits.Energy E;
equation
if (5 < time) and (time < 15) then P = 3;
  else P = 0;
  end if;
  der(E) = P;
end PowerGenerator;
```

How can I make the jumps at 5 and 15 sec into continuous transitions, where the derivative of the slope is finite? I've tried the `noEvent` and `smooth` functions, but I haven't been able to make them do what I need.

Edit:
The issue in my main model is that these events induce chattering, and so I also need it to work in real-time. Also in my full model, the events are state events, and so the time is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Scott G is good, but it only works well if the change just depends on time. A more general solution is to use a low-pass filter:

```
model PowerGenerator
  Modelica.SIunits.Power P(start=0);
  output Modelica.SIunits.Energy E;
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LowpassButterworth lowpassButterworth(f=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,20},{-20,40}})));
equation 
  if (5 < time) and (time < 15) then 
     P = 3;
  else 
     P = 0;
  end if;
  lowpassButterworth.u=P;
  der(E) = lowpassButterworth.y;
end PowerGenerator;
```

(I would recommend using connect-statements instead - but the above should also be legal Modelica.)

Comment: I'm not sure that the assertion that the solution I posted only work for time is correct. You can replace time with any variable that is a function of other variables. Even the "low" and "high" values can be functions of other variables. I've used this method in this fashion with success (so far ;) ).

Comment: You are right that it works for other variables. However, there must still be some variable explicitly involved and not just an arbitrary state event.

Comment: This method seems to work with some modifications in my model, however I still get some slight chattering when the equivalent of the step from a value to 0 occurs. Do you have any suggestions there?

Comment: @HansOlsson, I understand what you were indicating now. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a behavior like the code below is what you were looking?

```
model PowerGenerator
  Modelica.SIunits.Power Plow;
  Modelica.SIunits.Power Phigh;
  Modelica.SIunits.Power P(start=0);
  output Modelica.SIunits.Energy E;

  Modelica.SIunits.Power Pold(start=0);
  output Modelica.SIunits.Energy Eold;

equation 
  if (5 < time) and (time < 15) then
    Pold = 3;
  else
    Pold = 0;
  end if;
  der(Eold) = Pold;

  Plow = Modelica.Media.Air.MoistAir.Utilities.spliceFunction(3,0,time-5,1);
  Phigh = Modelica.Media.Air.MoistAir.Utilities.spliceFunction(0,3,time-15,1);
  P = Modelica.Media.Air.MoistAir.Utilities.spliceFunction(Phigh,Plow,time-10,1);
  der(E) = P;
end Power Generator;
```

Below is the plot of the outputs:
[image: Spine Output]

Comment: That looks very nice! Conceptually, that is indeed what I want it to do. Do you know if this method works during the simulation, as opposed to as a way to process the end results? I should probably clarify this in my original post.

Comment: @Bart Perhaps I don't quite follow your comment but this is occurring during the simulation. This method has worked for me for much more complex situations so far.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the correct terminology. What I meant to say was whether this effectively smooths the jumps before they happen? The issue in my main model is the chattering that occurs on step jumps for the 'flow' variable. Would this solution address that?

Comment: @Bart I believe it will but now your getting to the point where I think you will just have to try it out and verify.

Comment: I've tried to implement this method, but with limited success so far. In my actual model, the events are multiple, consecutive state events of unknown starting time and duration, and so I haven't been able to determine a general expression for the third argument of the spliceFunction.

Comment: @Bart, without more intimate knowledge of what you're doing it's hard to suggest a solution but the way I think of this approach is that it is best when you have "regions" for which you know the mathematical "zero crossing"  (i.e., third argument) between each region like in your post. Not sure if that is definable in your model but it sounds like it might not be and the LopassButterworth suggested by Hans is the way to go

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. In my full model the time of these zero-crossings are unknown, so that causes issues. Thanks for your suggestion!